# Can std::cout work with UTF-8 on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I want to make `std::cout` print an UTF-8 literal. This seems to be an easy task with gcc, but an extremely difficult one with Windows.

The code that I'm trying to get to work is:

```
std::cout << "Ελληνικά Русский 你好";
```

Environment:

- Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015
- Default encoding: 1251
- Console encoding: 866
- Source encoding: UTF-8 with BOM

Requirements:

- No changes to the line of code itself must be made
- Full Unicode range support
- Some setup code may be added in the beginning of `main()`

What I've tried:

- `#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")`
- `SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8); SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);`
- Set console font to Lucida Console system-wide
- `Use Unicode character set` in project properties
- Setup code from [this](https://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/unicode-part-1-windows-console-io-approaches/) blog

Nothing helped, and no StackOverflow answer solved the problem.

**Edit**

To get Unicode **partially** working, do the following:

- Call `initStreams()` from the listing below at the start
- Turn on `Use Unicode Character Set` in Project Settings
- Add `/utf-8` option

Not working:

- `wprintf`
- `cin`/`wcin`
- Chinese characters

`initStreams()` implementation:

```
#include <cassert>         // assert
#include <codecvt>          // std::codecvt_utf8 (C++11)
#include <stdexcept>        // std::exception
#include <streambuf>        // std::basic_streambuf
#include <iostream>         // std::cout, std::endl
#include <locale>           // std::locale
#include <memory>           // std::unique_ptr (C++11)

#undef  UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#undef  STRICT
#define STRING
#include <windows.h>    // MultiByteToWideChar

class OutputForwarderBuffer : public std::basic_streambuf<char>
{
public:
    using Base = std::basic_streambuf<char>;
    using Traits = Base::traits_type;
    using StreamBuffer = std::basic_streambuf<char>;
    using WideStreamBuffer = std::basic_streambuf<wchar_t>;
    using Base::int_type;
    using Base::char_type;

    OutputForwarderBuffer(
        StreamBuffer& existingBuffer,
        WideStreamBuffer* pWideStreamBuffer
    )
        : Base(existingBuffer)
        , pWideStreamBuffer_(pWideStreamBuffer)
    {
    }

    OutputForwarderBuffer(OutputForwarderBuffer const&) = delete;
    void operator=(OutputForwarderBuffer const&) = delete;

protected:
    std::streamsize xsputn(char const* s, std::streamsize n) override
    {
        if (n == 0) { return 0; }

        int const sourceSize = static_cast<int>(n);
        int const destinationSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, s, sourceSize, nullptr, 0);
        wideCharBuffer_.resize(static_cast<size_t>(sourceSize));

        int const nWideCharacters = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, s, sourceSize, &wideCharBuffer_[0], destinationSize);
        assert(nWideCharacters > 0 && nWideCharacters == destinationSize);

        return pWideStreamBuffer_->sputn(&wideCharBuffer_[0], destinationSize);
    }

    int_type overflow(int_type c) override
    {
        bool const cIsEOF = Traits::eq_int_type(c, Traits::eof());
        int_type const failureValue = Traits::eof();
        int_type const successValue = (cIsEOF ? Traits::not_eof(c) : c);

        if (!cIsEOF) {
            char_type const ch = Traits::to_char_type(c);
            std::streamsize const nCharactersWritten = xsputn(&ch, 1);

            return (nCharactersWritten == 1 ? successValue : failureValue);
        }
        return successValue;
    }

private:
    WideStreamBuffer* pWideStreamBuffer_;
    std::wstring wideCharBuffer_;
};

void setUtf8Conversion(std::basic_ios<wchar_t>& stream)
{
    stream.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>()));
}

bool isConsole(HANDLE streamHandle)
{
    DWORD consoleMode;
    return !!GetConsoleMode(streamHandle, &consoleMode);
}

bool isConsole(DWORD stdStreamId)
{
    return isConsole(GetStdHandle(stdStreamId));
}

void initStreams()
{
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

    setUtf8Conversion(std::wcout);
    setUtf8Conversion(std::wcerr);
    setUtf8Conversion(std::wclog);

    static OutputForwarderBuffer coutBuffer(*std::cout.rdbuf(), std::wcout.rdbuf());
    static OutputForwarderBuffer cerrBuffer(*std::cerr.rdbuf(), std::wcerr.rdbuf());
    static OutputForwarderBuffer clogBuffer(*std::clog.rdbuf(), std::wclog.rdbuf());

    std::cout.rdbuf(&coutBuffer);
    std::cerr.rdbuf(&cerrBuffer);
    std::clog.rdbuf(&clogBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `wcout`? `std::wcout << L"Ελληνικά Русский 你好";`?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I know that it will work. My goal is to avoid modifying that line of code, which works perfectly on Linux.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work? What happens?

Comment: @aardvarkk With SetConsoleCP, SetConsoleOutputCP and execution_character_set tricks applied together, it prints 16, 14 and 6 empty squares. These numbers match bytes in UTF-8 encoding of the three words.

Comment: @aardvarkk It's interesting that `printf()` prints the first two words correctly, but does not manage to print Chinese (font problem?). But still switching from `std::cout` to `printf()` is not an option.

Comment: On Windows/MSVCRT, `std::cout` cannot support Unicode, full stop. (You can get close with code page 65001 but there are insurmountable bugs in the console that break it, and Microsoft have neglected them forever, so don't expect them to get fixed.) `std::wcout` can be made to mostly-work through use of `_setmode` with `_O_UTF8`, but there are still problems (which the [code in the mentioned blog](https://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/) is all about working around) and you can't ever use a `cout`-related interface afterwards or it explodes.

Comment: You are usually best off either (a) reading/sending UTF-8 characters to the console anyway and not caring that Windows users see mojibake, or (b) using only your own input/output functions that switch between the Win32 WriteConsoleW et al interfaces on Windows and the standard library on other platforms where it is less grievously broken. But your requirements of (1) showing the right output on console via MSVCRT and (2) using unchanged `std::cout` calls are irreconcilable.

Comment: "*no StackOverflow answer solved the problem*" - there have been *TONS* of SO questions+answers that deal with UTF-8 in Windows consoles. That being said, since you know the output is UTF-8, and you now know that `std::cout` can't handle UTF-8 on Windows by default, one solution for your restrictive requirements might be to write a custom `streambuf` class that converts UTF-8 to UTF-16 and uses `WriteConsoleW()`, and then swap that class into `std::cout` using its `rdbuf()` method when needed.

Comment: Console window has limited Unicode support. I don't know how to print "你好" even in UTF16, let alone UTF8 which is not supported at all.

Comment: As it turned out (starting with) Windows 10 C runtime sends data to console one byte at a time (thus breaking multi-byte characters). I've updated my answer with workaround for that.

Comment: Note that in Windows 1809, there is a manifest option to use utf8 as ansi encoding. It might be a game changer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I'd do:

1. make sure your source files are utf-8 encoded and have correct content (open them in another editor, check glyphs and file encoding)
2. remove console from equation -- redirect output to a file and check it's content with utf-8-aware editor (just like with source code)
3. use /utf-8 cmdline option with MSVC2015+ -- this will force compiler to treat all source files as utf-8 encoded once and your string literals stored in resulting binary will be utf-8 encoded.
4. remove *iostreams* from equation (can't wait until for this library to die, tbh) -- use *cstdio*
5. at this point output should work (it does for me)
6. to get console output to work -- use SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8) and get it to use TrueType font that supports your *Unicode plane* (I suspect that for chinese characters to work in console you need a font installed in your system that supports related *Unicode plane* and your console should be configured to use it)
7. not sure about console input (never had to deal with that), but I suspect that SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8) should make it work with non-wide i/o
8. discard the idea of using wide i/o (wcout/etc) -- why would you do it anyway? Unicode works just fine with utf-8 encoded *char const**
9. once you reached this stage -- time to deal with *iostreams* (if you insist on using it). I'd disregard wcin/wcout for now. If they don't already work -- try imbue'ing related cin/cout with utf-8 locale.
10. the idea promoted by http://utf8everywhere.org/ is to convert to UCS-2 only when you make Windows API call. This makes your *OutputForwarderBuffer* unnecessary.
11. I guess (if you REALLY insist) now you can try getting wide iostreams to work. Good luck, I guess you'll have to reconfigure console (which will break non-wide i/o) or somehow get your wcout/wcin performing UCS2-to-UTF8 conversion on the fly (and only if it is connected to console).

**Edit:**
Starting from Windows 10 you also need this:

```
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IOFBF, 1024);    // on Windows 10+ we need buffering or console will get 1 byte at a time (screwing up utf-8 encoding)
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, 1024);
```

Unfortunately this also means that there is still a chance of screwing up your output if you fill buffer completely before next flush. Proper solution -- flush it manually (`endl` or `fflush()`) after every string sent to output (assuming each string is less than 1024). If only MS supported line-buffering...